# Unable to find an element by: [data-testid=“movieList”]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I need to test results in my ul from the movielistcomponent but i keep getting unbale to find element [data-testid=movieList]

My movielistComponent

```
      </section>
      {isLoaded ? (
        items.length === 0 ? (
          <div>No Results Found</div>
        ) : (
          <ul className="mt-50 styled" data-testid='movieList'>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <li className="slide-up-fade-in py-10" key={item.id}>
                {item.Title}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )
      ) : (
        <div className="mt-50 slide-up-fade-in" data-testid="no-result"></div>
      )}
    </div>
```

My test

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitFor , screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

const renderApp = () => render(<App/>);

afterEach(() => {
  fetchMock.restore();
  cleanup()
});

test('initial UI is rendered as expected', () => {
  let { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = renderApp();
  expect(getByTestId('app-input')).toHaveValue(null);
  expect(getByTestId('submit-button')).toHaveTextContent("Search");
  expect(screen.getByTestId('movieList').childNodes).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(queryByTestId('no-result')).toBe(null);
});
```

Comment: Are you querying `[data-testid=movieList]` or `[data-testid="movieList"]`? What isn't able to find it?

Comment: @EmileBergeron added test !

Comment: @DrewReese have no idea ! Thats why am here

Comment: @EmileBergeron well look at it now you will get it

Comment: Are `isLoaded` and `items.length === 0` both resolving to true and false respectively? If they are not `data-testid='movieList'` will never exist in the DOM and thus cannot be found by `getByTestId`

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing pieces. For the question to be complete, it would still be best to provide the minimal component (not just part of it, but removing any irrelevant parts is encouraged) that would trigger the issue with the test case.

Comment: @AlexMckay thats true! any idea how i can resolve that?

Comment: @AlexMckay All `getBy-` queries throw an error if no match, or more than one, is found. It *has* to match exactly one. See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries

Comment: @Namazzimercy pass `isLoaded` and `items` in as props. Then your test would look something like `render(<MovieList isLoaded={true} items={[{...}, {...}]} />)`. Not the only way, but certainly the simplest.

Comment: @DrewReese good point. OP you should take note.